# Changing database name for existing Asp.net MVC3 project

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on Asp.net MVC 3 project, I need change the database name for the project I tried  changing the database name in connection string & What happens is that when I pull the data it pulls from new DB where as when I try to insert data in some table it tries to insert in the old db. I am sure from where it is getting reference to the old DB name. Please HELP.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a different connection string for the inserts. You should make a search in the entier solution after the database name or parts of the connection string to find that connection string and modify it too.

Comment: I have already searched the complete solution and find nothing like that :(

Comment: Just found the mistake. there a trigger implemented in the database which was accessing the table with the old database name. Just Fixed that UP.